# python dictionary to sort values and return keys and values together

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

My dictionary values need to be sorted and the mapped keys to those values to be retrieved.
This is my snippet,

```
my_dict = {"q": 3, "G": 8, "a":1} 
list_zip = list(zip(my_dict.values(),my_dict.keys())) 
list_zip.sort()
```

is there better way of doing this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce to a one-liner by writing

```
sorted(zip(my_dict.values(), my_dict.keys()))
```

If it is OK to have keys show up first in `list_zip`, you can use

```
sorted(my_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

(requires `import operator`)

or

```
sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda tup: tup[1])
```